# Going up hill car slows down and engine rpm goes up

Tags: mercury, sable

2000 Mercury sable 3.0 DOHC transmission.
When driving up hill speed drops and engine rpm goes up. More gas no response.

Comment: Have you checked the automatic transmission fluid level?

Answer (score -1):

If it has a manual transmission, then your clutch is slipping and likely needs replacing.

Comment: That vehicle has only AX4N ATX automatic transaxles to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes that is the transmission in the car. Problem when going up a a steep hill rpm’s go up but car keeps slowing. Some times goes back when u let off gas pedal it will pick back up after you are over the hill and pick up speed.